# Styling multiple style props with styled-components on React Native

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I have been using Styled-components with React web for a while now, but recently I have started working on a React Native app which I decided to use styled-compoents in. It's been great when styling components that have just the `style` property, such as the default `react-native` components.

The problem I've been having though is when I need to style a more complex component that has multiple style properties such as `containerStyle`, `inputStyle`, and others.

When it's only one style property with a different name I can do the following:

```
const StyledBadge = styled(({ style, ...rest }) => {
  return <Badge {...rest} containerStyle={style} />;
})`
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
`;
```

This works flawlessly but when the component has multiple styles, I have no idea what to do:

```
const StyledList = styled(({ style, ...rest }) => {
  return <List {...rest} containerStyle={style} searchInputStyle={?} searchItemStyle={?} />;
})`
`;
```

With components like Gifted-React-Native-Chat is even worse because it has properties for passing properties as objects to its internal components, such as `messageProps`, `listViewProps`, `containerProps` and all of them have the `style` property.

Does anyone have any idea how to do that or if it's even possible?

I've been searching and trying to find a solution for this for a few days but I can't.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also curious about this as well for React Native. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey @Larbear, No I haven't =/

Comment: You have to use .attrs constructor mentioned here https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props but will lose the css syntax rules and have to use styles like you would with Stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks @Larbear, That's pretty awful but it gave me a really good idea on how to solve this. I'll leave an update here once I have it solved.

Comment: @Eric.M How did it go? Any update?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we ended up doing it.

Styled-components only work with the `style` prop but many custom components don't expose this prop. Instead they provide a `*Style` prop that gets passed to child component style props.

As an example, [react-native-material-textfield](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield) has 5 style props.
[image]

We use the `attrs` function to keep the organization of styles in one file with the rest of the styled components.

[image: styled-component attrs example]

This doesn't allow you to use traditional css syntax for the pseudo component, but it's the best we could think of to keep all styles organized.